# postgres sql query to identify rows with same foreign key, but non consecutive dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a `foreign_key_id` column and a `date` column.

For each row that has the same foreign key, there is a different date, and if I `order by foreign_key_id, date` ,  90% of the time all the dates are consecutive.

There are some edge cases though, where there are multiple entries with the same foreign_key that don't have consecutive dates.

Trying to come up with an easy way to identify all the `foreign_key_id` 's that don't have consecutive dates. Any ideas?

I was thinking of left joining on to a generated series, somehow partitioning by track id, but keep hitting a mental wall. My sql query editor keeps crashing, so that is adding some more unrelated frustration

EDIT:
I ended up doing an `order by foreign_key_id, date` , copying and pasting the result in excel, and then finding what I needed by doing this type of logic formula:
`=IF(      (B91 = B90),  (F91 =(F90 + 1))   ,    1 )`   , where b is the foreign key column and F is the date column

but wondering if something similar could be done in sql. here's what I had when I gave up and went to excel:

```
select to_char(date_range.days, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as x
 , data.*
from (
          select generate_series('2019-04-30'::date,'2019-11-05'::date, '1 day')::date as days
        ) as date_range
left join(
 select foreign_key_id, date
 from table_a
 order by foreign_key_id, date
) data on data.date = date_range.days
where foreign_key_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, sure. No joins needed either. Use `LAG(datecol) OVER(PARTITION BY foreignkeycol ORDER BY datecol)` to get the date of the previous row for the same fk, diff it to the current date to show how many intervals (days? Minutes?) have passed since that date and then wrap it all in something that does `WHERE thedifference <> 1` (Or however you define consecutive - if consecutive to you is "every 2 days" then it would be anything that doesn't have a difference of 2)

If you want both rows either side of the gap, use LEAD (same format as LAG) to get the next date and calc two diffs, then do `WHERE difftoprev <> 1 or difftonext <>1` etc

It would look something like this (untested)

```
WITH cte AS (

    SELECT foreignkeycol, datecol,
      LAG(datecol) OVER(PARTITION BY foreignkeycol ORDER BY datecol) as prevdate,
      LEAD(datecol) OVER(PARTITION BY foreignkeycol ORDER BY datecol) as nextdate
    FROM table
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 
  DATE_PART('day', datecol - prevdate) <> 1 OR
  DATE_PART('day', nextdate - datecol) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by foreign_key_id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date <> date + interval '1 day';
```

This will provide each row where the next row does not have the expected date.